# Translating Episode titles

Tags: verbs

I'm trying to translate some episode titles for a 1974 show called 電撃！！ストラダ５, and two of the episode titles are 殺人コンピューターをぶちこわせ！ and ハネムーン作戦でぶちあたれ！ What are ぶちこわせ and ぶちあたれ? I can't find anything about them.